# Permission denied (public key) on ssh connection to a docker

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, ssh-keygen

I am trying to setup an ssh connection to a docker using ssh keys, i have used ssh_keygen and copied the .pub file to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the container, however i get the following error on connection

```
me@172.17.0.2: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have done this following the ssh manual page so I struggle to understand why my keys wont pass.

Container side my home is set as /root, which is why I put it in the /root/.ssh/authorize_keys folder.

I also modified the sshd_config file following options:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

I had tried setting PermitEmptyPasswords and PasswordAuthentication to yes but would still be refused login if i just gave an empty string as password.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Those kind of server configuration are not on topic here. You might find better luck on [su] or [sf], but mind to read their on topic pages. From my experience, though, something that could get in the way are permissions on files and folder, if the permissions are too lax, sshd will discard them.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say you copied the .pub file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` you really mean that you have copied the content of your public key into the `authorized_keys` file? I ask because you mention the `/root/.ssh/authorize_keys` as a folder.

Comment: Yes i copied it to '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys', which was actually linked to my mistake because root is actually the name of the profile in the docker and my ssh connection was using my ubuntu profile by default, which didnt exist in the docker, i still can't make the ssh key works correctly but am now able to connect via password.